# Duplicate record on same table and rename the field value

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, record

I'm having exact the same problem as described in this URL and adding something extra on my issue [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213054/rename-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

I have list of products and I want to duplicate by selecting all products I can done that..but now I want to rename the product name for example

```
product id   product name
  1             A
  2             B
  3             C
```

I will select the all these three products or anyone of the product and duplicate, then the product name should be like below

```
product id  product name
  1            A
  2            B
  3            C
  4            A(1)
  5            B(1)
  6            C(1)
```

If again I copied the product name B only then it should be

```
product id  product name
  1            A
  2            B
  3            C
  4            A(1)
  5            B(1)
  6            C(1)
  7            B(2)
```

How could I do this in my code?

Comment: That's what UNIQUE constraints in databases are for.

Comment: What are you talking about? He wants to duplicate data, not prevent duplicates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$count = SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE product_name LIKE 'B%';

INSERT INTO `table` product_name VALUES ( 'B(<?=$count;?>)' );
```