# Rename duplicate rows in MySQL, WHERE IN () - dosen't works fine

Tags: mysql, sql, rename, where-in

I started from here:
[Rename duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213054/rename-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

```
SELECT  mid(s,instr(s,',')+1) as dubid
FROM (
      SELECT group_concat(id ORDER BY id ASC) s, count(*) c
      FROM   `...`
      GROUP BY field
      HAVING c > 1) as z
```

Seems to work fine and returns dubid rows like

```
1
3,5,6
8
10,15
```

So I made this:

```
set @suf:=0;
UPDATE `table_cf_vendlist` 
SET    `cf_vendlist` = concat(`cf_vendlist`, ' \(', @suf:=@suf+1,'\)')
WHERE  `cf_vendlistid` IN ({SELECT  mid...})
```

But it renames only first ID from each row. So how I can make it work? Also how to nullyfy @suf counter for each row?
And no PHP. MySQL only!

```
set @suf:=0;
set @last := 0;
UPDATE `vtiger_cf_vendlist` t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(cf_vendlistid) as id, cf_vendlist
   FROM   vtiger_cf_vendlist 
   GROUP BY cf_vendlist) AS unique1 
ON (t1.cf_vendlist = unique1.cf_vendlist)
SET    t1.`cf_vendlist` = concat(t1.`cf_vendlist`, ' \(', 
         @suf := if (@last = t1.cf_vendlistid, @suf+1, 1 and @last := t1.cf_vendlist), '\)')
WHERE t1.cf_vendlistid <> unique1.id
```

But I am not shure where is t1.`cf_vendlist`, and where is unique1.`cf_vendlist`. Also result is 0 and 1 in names, no increments and zeroing for each id set. But still, loks like it renamed everyting is needed.

Here is some data to run with sqlfiddle.com:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_cf_vendlist` (
  `cf_vendlistid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cf_vendlist` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cf_vendlistid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=78 ;


INSERT INTO `table_cf_vendlist` (`cf_vendlistid`, `cf_vendlist`) VALUES
(2, 'Поставщик 2'),
(3, 'Поставщик 3'),
(4, 'Поставщик 4'),
(5, 'del 1'),
(6, 'Поставщик 1 (1)'),
(7, 'Поставщик 1 (2)'),
(8, 'пост 66'),
(9, 'пост 77'),
(10, 'пост 67'),
(11, 'пост 5'),
(12, '123'),
(13, '102'),
(14, 'пост 5 (1)'),
(15, 'пост 70'),
(47, 'Поставщик 1'),
(48, 'Поставщик 2'),
(49, 'Поставщик 3'),
(50, 'Поставщик 4'),
(51, 'del 1'),
(52, 'Поставщик 1'),
(53, 'Поставщик 1'),
(54, 'пост 5'),
(55, '124523452346256456'),
(56, 'пост 66'),
(57, 'пост 77'),
(58, 'пост 5'),
(59, 'пост 5'),
(60, 'пост 5'),
(61, 'пост 67'),
(62, '123'),
(63, '123'),
(64, '123'),
(65, 'пост 5'),
(66, 'пост 68'),
(67, '123'),
(68, '123'),
(69, '123'),
(70, '123'),
(71, '102'),
(72, 'пост 5'),
(73, 'пост 70');
```

UPD

We got

```
52  Поставщик 1 (11)
53  Поставщик 1 (12)
```

Instead of

```
52  Поставщик 1 (3)
53  Поставщик 1 (4)
```

and

```
48  Поставщик 2 (13)
49  Поставщик 3 (14)
50  Поставщик 4 (15)
```

Instead of

```
48  Поставщик 2 (2)
49  Поставщик 3 (2)
50  Поставщик 4 (2)
```

UPD 2:

```
set @suf:=0;
set @last := 0;
UPDATE     table_cf_vendlist t
INNER JOIN (SELECT cf_vendlistid, concat(cf_vendlist, ' (', 
                   @suf := if (STRCMP(@last1, cf_vendlist) = 0,
                               @suf+1,
                               1 or @last := cf_vendlist), ')') as new_label
           FROM (
                 SELECT     t1.cf_vendlistid, t1.cf_vendlist, unique1.id as reference_id
                 FROM       table_cf_vendlist t1
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT  MIN(cf_vendlistid) as id, cf_vendlist
                             FROM     table_cf_vendlist
                             GROUP BY cf_vendlist) AS unique1
                             ON       t1.cf_vendlist = unique1.cf_vendlist
                 ORDER BY   cf_vendlist, cf_vendlistid
                ) AS t1_sorted

           WHERE   t1_sorted.cf_vendlistid <> t1_sorted.reference_id)

           AS t1_sorted_labeled

ON         t.cf_vendlistid = t1_sorted_labeled.cf_vendlistid

SET        t.cf_vendlist = t1_sorted_labeled.new_label;
```

works. But 1 or @last := cf_vendlist is a hack that allows to return 1 or 0(and) instead of `cf_vendlist` string (see my comment below)

Comment: it doesn't work because dubid is a string like '5,6'. So, you get  cf_vendlistid in ('5,6'). I'm actually surprised it renames the first row. Can you make a schema in sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Looks like I need to login to save.

Comment: Sorry, I can't resist: this would be so easy with a different DBMS: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/20889/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, good to know, actually, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9722c8/7). To follow how it works,

1) look at the subquery t1_sorted

```
SELECT     t1.cf_vendlistid, t1.cf_vendlist, unique1.id as reference_id
FROM       table_cf_vendlist t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(cf_vendlistid) as id, cf_vendlist
            FROM   table_cf_vendlist
            GROUP BY cf_vendlist) AS unique1
ON          t1.cf_vendlist = unique1.cf_vendlist
WHERE       t1.cf_vendlistid <> unique1.id
ORDER BY    cf_vendlist, cf_vendlistid
```

which returns results like in fig. 1.

[image: sorted data with reference id associated with each group]

2a) In subquery t1_sorted_labeled, the results are projected to remove the first occurrence of the cf_vendlist in each group and

2b) an extra field new_label is created with the cf_vendlist and (copy number)

3) Finally, the original query is joined with this subquery in the UPDATE statement, which merely copies new_label to cf_vendlist

Thus, complete answer:

```
set @suf:=0;
set @last := 0;

UPDATE     table_cf_vendlist t
INNER JOIN (SELECT cf_vendlistid, concat(cf_vendlist, ' (', 
               @suf := if (STRCMP(@last, cf_vendlist) = 0,
                           @suf+1,
                           1 and length(@last := cf_vendlist)), ')') as new_label
           FROM (
                 SELECT     t1.cf_vendlistid, t1.cf_vendlist, unique1.id as reference_id
                 FROM       table_cf_vendlist t1
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT  MIN(cf_vendlistid) as id, cf_vendlist
                             FROM     table_cf_vendlist
                             GROUP BY cf_vendlist) AS unique1
                             ON       t1.cf_vendlist = unique1.cf_vendlist
                 ORDER BY   cf_vendlist, cf_vendlistid
                ) AS t1_sorted

           WHERE   t1_sorted.cf_vendlistid <> t1_sorted.reference_id)

           AS t1_sorted_labeled

ON         t.cf_vendlistid = t1_sorted_labeled.cf_vendlistid

SET        t.cf_vendlist = t1_sorted_labeled.new_label;
```

BTW, you should really have an index on cf_vendlist.

Comment: Wow, that will take a time to understand. And still something wron with numbers. Index is good idea, but not in this case, because it is patch for systems alredy in use, and requre to run only once.

Comment: yes you are right, it looks correct in the beginning but then it goes astray. I'll have another look at it.

Comment: Aha! "@ last = cf_vendlist" - you can't just compare strings in mysql like that. STRCMP(@last1, cf_vendlist) = 0 - that is works.   But I am not shure you can use cheat "1 and @ last := cf_vendlist" so there is "0" instead of wrong numbers.  You can use "1 or @ last := cf_vendlist" - that fixes all, but it's a hack, that works only if you need to return 0 or 1. Usless if you need to start from -1, 2, 3 or string (assuming someone else will read this and in need of such solutions).

Comment: well spotted. The reason for 0 was that the logical "and" of a number with a string returns 0. The "or" cannot work because mysql short-circuits logical operations, so the @last:= cf_vendlist will not take place. The solution is to use 1 and length(@last:= cf_vendlist). I hope you can accept my answer now.

Comment: Actually it works with "or". I mean it returns true(1) or false(2). And I assume that there is no way to assign a value to a variable and return some other complex value. But using logical operations is a trick, that allows to return 0 or 1 and assign a value to a variable, right?  And of course I can accept you answer. Actually I wanted to tell you many thanks for so much helping me with my problem!

Comment: no problem! But I confees I don't see how the "or" can work because in that case the "last" will not change.

Comment: It will because it need to be calculated before comparison with 1

Comment: nope, mysql stops computing the "or" when it finds 1. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html (comments at the end)

Comment: Nnn-gh! You right. More hack in code. Is there no way to use IF-THEN http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html outside functions?

Comment: that's only for stored procedures, which could be used to solve your problem using 3GL programming (SQL is 4GL). But I don't see what worries you so much about the query. A common approach to solve your type of problem is to use variables and using "and" is a common trick. The real issue you have there might the lack of index on cf_vendlist if the table is big.

Comment: I'm just lerning - that's all. Luckily the table is not very big.

Comment: Ou, yes, sorry. Didn't know how to do that:)